# Is there a QList type datastructure in STL or Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, qt4

just a brief QList intro, QList is similar to QVector and STL vector but in addition it also reserves some space at the beginning; (and in the end too)
I am looking for something similar in STL , if not atleast Boost

Reserving space at the beginning improves prepending or removing the first item (constant time), because the buffer can grow backwards. Insertion is improved depending on the position of insertion.
So does anyone know of a similar data structure in STL/C++??
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::deque` provides front and back insertion removal at constant time, if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: yep.. thats what I was looking for,

Answer (score 3):

If you want efficient insertion and removal at the beginning and end of a sequence, use a `std::deque`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know an upper limit on container size and don't plan on mid-container inserts you could use [boost::circular_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html).

If you are doing a lot of mid-container inserts `deque` would be the a better choice than `vector` since it (typically) groups members into fixed-size blocks, rather than one contiguous block of memory.

Note - [QList](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qlist.html#details) actually states that it uses an array of pointers to objects, if they are non-trivial.  To simulate this in C++, you would use `deque<MyClass*>` or (better) some smart pointer wrapper on `MyClass` such as `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, to prevent excessive copying of `MyClass` in housekeeping.

> Internally, QList is represented as
>   an array of pointers to items of type
>   T. If T is itself a pointer type or a
>   basic type that is no larger than a
>   pointer, or if T is one of Qt's shared
>   classes, then QList stores the
>   items directly in the pointer array.
>   For lists under a thousand items, this
>   array representation allows for very
>   fast insertions in the middle, and it
>   allows index-based access.

Comment: And actually, I think if T is a movable type object then QList will store directly. I think so, but correct me if am wrong. But thanks Steve

Comment: @reddy the sum total of my Qt knowledge is above - I only looked this up to get correct context here.  However if you mean a type smaller the same size as a pointer such as `int`, `char` etc with trivial copy construction and assignment, then that's what I took the excerpt I cited to imply.  'Movable' is a loaded word in the context of C++0x.

Comment: Steve, I didn't know moveable was actually C++ concept, I thought that was from Qt. Thank you again :D

Comment: @reddy - there are new features in C++0x to allow more efficient 'move' constructors to be built - http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2009/06/07/the-move-constructor-in-visual-c-2010/ - I don't want to confuse you, and that's what I meant.